# Trapped in with Asp.Net Dynamic Data with Linq2SQL, where to move next?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

for some years, Dynamic Data with Linq2SQL served as a cool and easy tool to create administration projects But it's getting more and more problematic to maintain these projects after 5 years, because from the Asp addons lifecycle perspective it's a deadend.

Does anyone faced a similar decision, where to move next?

Comment: I've been developing DynamicData websites for the last year, should I be worried? What do you mean by Asp add-ons and what deadend? What's wrong with LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fell into that trap at a previous job where a lot of the projects were "quick and dirty" and then became mainline applications.  My suggestion is to describe the problem to your management and when the next change comes down the line, allocate some extra time to translate some of the core ORM to Entity Framework.

Since you already have the DB in place, you can use EDMX files, then use those generated classes as your Model, or create one on top.

Be sure to explain to your management that putting in the time now to create a better core will pay dividends later on as maintenance will become easier, since you will no longer be working around Dynamic Data's shortcomings.